# SQL Unable to call certain scalar-valued functions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am working on a db in microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012 and I have run into a problem which I cannot solve nor can I find the solution online.

I seem to be unable to call certain Scalar-valued functions from other scalar-valued functions or anywhere for that matter. When I start typing: dbo.fn... I only get 3 out of 5 functions that were created in the db.

What I have noticed is, that both of the missing functions accept 2 parameters. Is that the issue ? Is there a special way to call a function with 2 parameters?

Comment: The problem is not in the `paramaters` , did you try to refresh your db? or just try to drag your function to the query editor

Comment: I did and also restarted the entire program, I also deleted and recreated both functions.

Comment: Are you sure it is being created in the `dbo` schema?

Comment: When recreating the functions I explicitly went to the folder containing scalar-valued functions id db, right clicked and created it from there.

Comment: Try : `CREATE FUNCTION dbo.YourFunctionName`

Comment: you have to restart SSMS and try again... that happens all the time.

Comment: Restarting it worked! Strangely it did not work when I restarted it earlier. But it is fixed now. Thank you for the help.

Comment: appreciate if you can +1

Comment: Instead of restarting the SSMS you could always go for Ctrl + R, that refreshed the schema.